# Find the sum with induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Find the sum

$\sum_{j=1}^n 2^{-j}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}$

for all $n=3,4,...$. I need to use induction.

I don't know how to start, can you show me?

Comment: First step is to guess the result. The first few sums are $\frac12, \frac34,\frac78,\frac{15}{16}$, so what is your guess?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen My guess is the sum is 1

Comment: The *limit* of the series of sums is 1, but you're being asked about the individual terms. Do you notice anything about the numerator and denominator?

Comment: What is the difference between the values @HagenvonEitzen gave and the limit?

Comment: @copper.hat The difference between the values and the limit is approaching zero.

Comment: I mean what is the formula for the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let
$$s_n=\sum_{j=1}^n 2^{-j}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+...+\frac{1}{2^n}$$

$$\begin{align}
s_n&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}\\
\frac{s_n}{2}&=\quad\quad\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^n}+\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}
\end{align}$$

$$\frac{s_n}{2}-s_n=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}-\frac{1}{2}$$

$$s_n\left(\frac12-1\right)=\frac{1-2^n}{2^{n+1}}$$
$$s_n=\frac{2^n-1}{2^{n}}$$

Now for $n=1$

$$s_1=\frac{2^1-1}{2^{1}}=\frac12$$

for $n=k$

$$s_k=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k}=\frac{2^k-1}{2^{k}}$$

for $n=k+1$

$$s_{k+1}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^k-1}{2^{k}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}=\frac{2^{k+1}-2}{2^{k+1}}+\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}\\\implies s_{k+1}=\frac{2^{k+1}-1}{2^{k+1}}$$

Now if above formula is true for $k$ then it's also true for $k+1$ and then using Principle of Mathematical Induction..

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach: Look for equations that the series satisfies. There is no recipe here, just an approach.

Let $S_n = {1\over 2} +\cdots + {1 \over 2^n}$. Then note that we have
$2 S_n = 1+ S_{n-1}$ and $S_n = S_{n-1}+{1 \over 2^n}$. Subtracting the second from the first gives $S_n = 1- {1 \over 2^n}$.